# Rerunning TestNG test causes test to run forever

Tags: java, testng

I have a test like this:

```
public class Test1 extends AbstractTest{
@Test(retryAnalyzer=Retry.class)
public void test(){
    System.out.println(this.getClass().getName() + " running");
    Assert.fail();
}
```

I have a retry class like this:

```
public class Retry implements IRetryAnalyzer{
    private int retryCount = 0;
    private int maxRetryCount = 3;

    public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
        if (retryCount < maxRetryCount) {
            System.out.println("Retrying test " 
                               + result.getName() + " with status "
                               + getResultStatusName(result.getStatus()) 
                               + " for the " + (retryCount+1) + " time(s).");
            retryCount++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getResultStatusName(int status) {
        String resultName = null;
        if(status==1)
            resultName = "SUCCESS";
        if(status==2)
            resultName = "FAILURE";
        if(status==3)
            resultName = "SKIP";
        return resultName;
    }
}
```

When I run the test, it repeats indefinitely, giving this as console output:

```
tests.Test1 running
Retrying test test with status FAILURE for the 1 time(s).
tests.Test1 running
Retrying test test with status FAILURE for the 2 time(s).
Retrying test test with status FAILURE for the 3 time(s).
tests.Test1 running
tests.Test1 running
tests.Test1 running
tests.Test1 running
tests.Test1 running
tests.Test1 running
tests.Test1 running
tests.Test1 running
```

And so forth...

Why does it fail to run the second time? Why does it run indefinitely?  How can I make it have the desired behavior of running, then retrying up to 3 times or however many i set MaxRetryCount to?

Comment: Which version do you use? Try the latest because it is supposed to work: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/test/java/test/retryAnalyzer/RetryAnalyzerTest.java

Comment: 6.8.21 is the version.  I'll check for a later version.

Comment: This worked.  If you make this an answer, I will mark it accepted. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the latest because it is supposed to work: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/test/java/test/retryAnalyzer/RetryAnalyzerTest.java